# Bootstrap card not showing up in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

For some reason in one of my partial views, the card is not showing in the correct format, the layout of the card is correct but it's just plain text format it seems that the view is missing the bootstrap. In the home view and other views bootstrap works well. Bootstrap is also included in the BundleConfig. Also, I'm using bootstrap 4.4.1 which is the latest.

The code of my partial view is:

```
@model Testing.Models.Cars

<div class="card">
   <h5 class="card-header">Header Title</h5>
   <div class="card-body">
       <h5 class="card-title">The title</h5>
       <h5 class="card-title">A name</h5>
       <div class="row">
            @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                   @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.Id })
                </div>
            }
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = Model.Id })
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = Model.Id })
            </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code in my view:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Testing.Models.Cars>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index View</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   <p>
        Find car by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchCar", ViewBag.CurrentFilter 
         as string)
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
   </p>
}

<br />

<table class="table">
   @foreach (var car in Model)
   {
        @Html.Partial("_PartialView", car)
    }
</table>

<br />

Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of 
@Model.PageCount
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { currentFilter = 
ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```

Comment: Is this card nested inside a `.container` somewhere?

Comment: Since it is in a partial view I'm calling it from another view in a foreach statement

Comment: do you add bootstrap 4 CDN or package?

Comment: No, it's not added in the views, but it is added in the Bundleconfig. Bootstrap is called only in the main layout

Comment: Also, I've tried adding Scripts.Render and the bootstrap but still, it doesn't work

Comment: Can you show your code where you put this partial view?

Comment: @rjs123431 Edited it

Comment: hmm, looks fine. did you test to clear out Index view and manually add div elements with class cards in it?

Comment: No I didn't, I just copied the card and added stuff to it, let me check!

Comment: Just did it but still persists...

Comment: you mention that "In home view and other views bootstrap works well" but you did not mention there are cards on those views.

Comment: you can look at the bootrap.css file, verify if there are .card style there, or you may replace the `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")` in _Layout with the bootstrap CDN
goodluck

Comment: No there aren't any other card classes, in the Home there is a jumbotron class and in the other views there are bootstrap class buttons etc. Thanks